How to extract data as columns from json format string in snowflake where each record has different values in json
A sample of the data is as below:

the properties column is a varchar column in the table. It can have any combination of name & value properties. It can also be null for a lot of records. I want the output to be as follows - all the properties within every json to be a new column:

How can this be achieved in snowflake?
Additional details:
The properties column has json formats within list,
[
  {
    "name": "_is-bundle",
    "value": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "name": "_bundle-id",
    "value": "xyz-abc"
  }
]

I use an ETL tool but I could not achieve what I wanted. I tried the lateral flatten method on snowflake but it throws an error for the properties column being varchar.

Hi, Please post your failed attempt to use FLATTEN you should be able to get what I think you want out of that.

Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text appropriately formatted

One option is to first flatten the JSON and then use case statements to identify when certain values belong in certain columns. (Assuming you already have a table with the JSON values in it, you can just skip the CTE in this query I've created below.)
WITH JSON_DATA AS (SELECT (PARSE_JSON('[
        {"name": "_is-bundle", "value": "Yes"},
        {"name": "_bundle-id", "value": "xyz-abc"}
    ]')) AS json_data
               UNION ALL
               SELECT (PARSE_JSON('[
        {"name": "_is-bundle", "value": "Yes"},
        {"name": "_bundle-id", "value": "fig-gif"}
    ]'))
               UNION ALL
               SELECT (PARSE_JSON('[
        {"name": "_gift-grp", "value": "axx25"},
        {"name": "_is-free", "value": "Yes"}
    ]'))
               UNION ALL
               SELECT (PARSE_JSON('[
        {"name": "_group-child", "value": "Yes"},
        {"name": "_group-id", "value": "100nj"},
        {"name": "_child-id", "value": "600nj"}
    ]')))
SELECT
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_is-bundle'
       THEN flattened.value:value END   AS is_bundle,
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_bundle-id'
       THEN flattened.value:value END   AS bundle_id,
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_gift-grp'
       THEN flattened.value:value END    AS gift_grp,
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_is-free'
       THEN flattened.value:value END     AS is_free,
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_group-child'
       THEN flattened.value:value END AS group_child,
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_group-id'
       THEN flattened.value:value END    AS group_id,
   CASE WHEN flattened.value:name = '_child-id'
       THEN flattened.value:value END    AS child_id
FROM JSON_DATA,
 LATERAL FLATTEN(input => JSON_DATA.json_data) AS FLATTENED;

